# problema al establecer un file en python

Tags: python, sqlite3

lo que pasa es que estoy siguiendo un tutorial de youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QqDQEZ3FTI   y la hora de implementar la base de datos que consta de estar sepadara del codigo original no me da acceso o me dice que no se puede crear.
adjunto imagnes del codigo y del problema  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la imagen del problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aclaro que si dejo la direccion de la base de datos con peliculas.db queda resuelto pero no queda ubicada donde quiero